# How to define non-trivial necessary and sufficient conditions?

Tags: soft-question

Mathematicians often speak of finding necessary and sufficient conditions for some property $P$. But $P$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $P$. So, how do we determine what a non-trivial necessary and sufficient condition is? Is there a formal and rigorous definition of such a thing?

Comment: No, there is not.  This is far too vague to have any universal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Why should there be? $Q$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $P$ iff $P$ and $Q$  are logically equivalent. It is a value judgement whether the logical equivalence is non-trivial.